# Force SSRS 2005 to print a new page

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005, report

I have a field on the footer that may contain more text the the textbox would support. If it does, I need the report to print another page, even if it's completely empty, containing only the footer field.

Basically, if a condition is  true, I want the report to print a new page, displaying my footer in it, even if there's nothing else  to be printed.

How can I achieve this, preferably with field expressions?

And if you have a solution that's not a field expression (external code for example), could you also point me to the basics of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On any block you have the property PageBreak, you can choose begin, end or none. By choosing end, a page break will be insered after the block.

Comment: Right, and how could I insert a page break if a determined condition is true? Unfortunately, the "PageBreakAtStart" property does not accept an exression...

Comment: Hum, i don't know if it could solve your issue, but you can play with the XML of the .Rdl file, depending of your data, you can add the pagebreak tag quite easily :).

Comment: The page break helped me. What I did was divide my giant field into two fields, display a substring of it inside the original box, and then check if the other one has any value. If it has, display it, with the page break, letting it fill the entire page. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

=iif(Globals!PageNumber Mod 2,True,False)   this helped me to show (visibility) a text box on even pages only from my footer